# Change multiple elements colour based on background colour

Tags: javascript, css

I have a fixed menu which consists of multiple elements. I am trying to find a way to have all these elements change colour depending on the background colour.

The elements are a

```
#page::before,
.logo-scroll
```

both of these elements have a white border (no fill)

The links of the main navigation .main-navigation and their borders are white

The logo which is white. I also have a black version.

My site is made up of 3 section colours, black, white and yellow.

I would like the items to switch to black when the background sections are either yellow or white.

The website is very much a work in progress but you can see it here:
https://www.sheree-new.shereewalker.com

I have tried this for the logo

https://eduardoboucas.com/blog/2017/09/25/svg-clip-path-logo-colour.html

but could not get it to work. I tried mix-blend mode for the elements but it makes the lines blue when on the yellow. I tried to do mix-blend-mode and THEN use the desaturate or greyscale filter but with no luck.

This is perhaps too much to tackle in one question but I thought perhaps there was a plugin that handled this in Wordpress?

Essentially what I need is this for all elements
https://codepen.io/whatthephuc/pen/QQagBj

The header which contains the left and right nav elements:

```
<div class="logo-scroll">
        <div class="scroll-text">
            <a href="/home"><img width="53px" height="260px" src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/sheree-walker-web-design-edinburgh-vertical-01.svg"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'sheree_walker' ); ?></button>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
            ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

The CSS

```
header#masthead {
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    width: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top:30px;
}

#site-navigation {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
    position: relative;
    right: -75px;
    width: calc(100vh - 60px);
}

.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 23px 20px 21px 20px;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: 'NeurialGrotesk';
}

.main-navigation li {
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.main-navigation li:nth-child(n+1) {
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.main-navigation a {
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}

#page::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.logo-scroll {
    position: fixed;
    left: 30px;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    width: 75px;
}

.scroll-text {
    position: fixed;
}
```

All the sections have classes of either yellow or white - the default background is black.

Any help or advice on a suitable plugin would be great.

**Edit - something like this would be perfect if it applied to background colours

https://github.com/kennethcachia/background-check

I have also just tried this which sort of works but also generates a background colour at random

```
contrast();

function contrast() {

    var R, G, B, C, L;

    $( "main-navigation a" ).each(function() {

        R = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
        G = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
        B = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));

        $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'rgb(' + R + ',' + G + ',' + B + ')' );

        C = [ R/255, G/255, B/255 ];

        for ( var i = 0; i < C.length; ++i ) {

            if ( C[i] <= 0.03928 ) {

                C[i] = C[i] / 12.92

            } else {

                C[i] = Math.pow( ( C[i] + 0.055 ) / 1.055, 2.4);

            }

        }

        L = 0.2126 * C[0] + 0.7152 * C[1] + 0.0722 * C[2];

        if ( L > 0.179 ) {

            $( this ).css( 'color', 'black' );

        } else {

            $( this ).css( 'color', 'white' );

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: A solution would be using `mix-blend-mode: difference;` Please take a look at this article: [Methods for Contrasting Text Against Backgrounds](https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/)

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your answer but as mentioned I have already tried this. The result is blue on yellow not black. I tried applying a desaturate or greyscale filter after to make the blue look black but it did not work.

Comment: Hi. Don't know of wp pluggins but if you can make [https://eduardoboucas.com/blog/2017/09/25/svg-clip-path-logo-colour.html] work for the logo, you could make the lines in svgs instead of border since they are fixed maybe. And then could use the same trick.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very basic way to control text color with javascript.

You can control exactly where you want the color changes based on the scroll height.

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');
var d = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var colors = ['white', 'red', 'black'];
var offset = 0.025;
var scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight-innerHeight;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  var scroll = scrollY/scrollHeight;
  p.style.color = colors[0];
  var h = 0;
  for (var i=1; i<d.length; i++) {
    h += d[i-1].offsetHeight;
    if (scroll > (h/scrollHeight)-offset) p.style.color = colors[i];
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
}
.black {
  background: black;
  height: 150vh;
}
.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
}
.white {
  background: white;
  height: 200vh;
}
p {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<p>I'll change color on scroll</p>
<div class="black"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="white"></div>
```

Comment: Hi there - that's great thanks - will this work when section heights change responsively?

Comment: Now it will, I've updated the code in order to automatically take account each height. You can change the Y offset where the color change happens and all the colors are stored in one array. Note that the `scrollHeight` value should be updated on `resize` in order to be really responsive.

Comment: Hi There - thank you for this. i am very sorry but I can't get it to work. 

It's links I need to change so I tried changing the 'p' in the code to 'a' but it didn't work. Also can you explain how you are specifying which text colour belongs to which background colour? It looks like it is just done in order of appearance - how would this work on pages where the colour sequence was different? Thanks again

Comment: By inspecting the website you posted in the question, I can see the you must replace the white colored `img` text for real text inside `<a href="/home">`. You can rotate it with CSS `transform: rotate(-90deg)`. Also you can replace `a` selector in the code for `.logo-scroll a` and the `p` selector for `.super-large-h1, .wp-block-group.has-background, .site-footer`. Note you will get 5 elements with the following backgrounds: black, yellow, yellow, photo, black, as eg: one possible corresponding array of text colors would be `['white', 'black', 'black', 'white', 'white']`.

Comment: You will have to adjust the code offset to track the position of your moving `<a>` link. You can always open a new question if you find any issues in your tries.

Comment: Hi there. I am trying to implement these changes but there is no a selector in your code? Also - how do I apply this to pages with a different colour sequence? thanks again

Comment: Seems like you don't know exactly how selectors work so take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors
In the code above, 'p' and 'div' are selectors that return the `<p>` tag and the `<div>` tags. To change the color sequence just change the `colors` array with the colors you want for your text.

Comment: Hi there, I do know how they work - I am confused because you have asked me to change the 'a' selector in the code, Is that a typo because there is not an 'a' present in your code. I am referring to changing the colour sequence for different pages. So the home page might go black, yellow, black but the projects page might go, yellow, black, white etc. Thanks again

Comment: You said "changing the 'p' in the code to 'a' " so I thought you knew what selector I was talking about, I'm sorry if it confused you. As I said, you just need to change the array to match the colors you want.

Comment: Here's a JSBin with what you need to do: https://jsbin.com/difubafira/edit?output
You can write a different script for each page or you can use an if statement checking the window.location parameter.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for this - when I look at the JSBin however it doesn't appear to work? Am I missing something? Sorry to take up so much of your time!

Comment: Try this link https://jsbin.com/kokoduvaga/edit?html,output 
In the previous link, the html still has the `<img>` tag inside `<a href="/home">`

Comment: HI there - this would be perfect except I need it to change colours when it's partially over = like this
https://codepen.io/whatthephuc/pen/QQagBj
sorry I should have bee more specific

Comment: For that you can use multiple elements and hide them using clip-path. Notice that it don't have the best browser support yet https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: Hi there. Hmm yes okay, I think I will try a clip path and then maybe try to use mix-blend mode as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic implementation using JS + CSS, that adds coloured children to the navigation block on scroll on resize:

```js
addEventListener("scroll", fixNavigation);
addEventListener("resize", fixNavigation);
if (document.readyState === "complate") fixNavigation();
else addEventListener("load", fixNavigation);

function fixNavigation() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#nav>.nav-background")].forEach(item => item.remove());
  var nav = document.getElementById("nav");
  var scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var currentHeight = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(function(box) {
    var navBackground = document.createElement("div");
    navBackground.className = "nav-background";
    nav.appendChild(navBackground);
    navBackground.setAttribute("style", `top: ${currentHeight - scrolled}px; background: ${box.getAttribute("other-color")};`);
    currentHeight += box.offsetHeight;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 40px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff8888;
}

.green {
  background: #a2ffa2;
}

.blue {
  background: #7171ff;
}

.nav-background {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">

</div>
<div class="box red" other-color="purple"></div>
<div class="box green" other-color="black"></div>
<div class="box blue" other-color="yellow"></div>
```